# How to do svn update without password on crontab

Tags: bash, svn, ubuntu, ssh, cron

I'm new to svn and ssh. I'm trying to do svn update of 5 repositories in my local system every 3 hours on crontab.
So, to achieve this I have setup `ssh passwordless login` using the below steps:

1. `ssh-keygen`
2. `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub test@repo.test.in`
3. I did `ssh test@repo.test.in`

Till here it works fine for me. I'm able to login without password.
But, when I try to do `sudo svn update` on the 5 repositories, it is propmpting for password. 
How to make svn update without password. Is there any way that I can do update of the repositories every 3 hours on cron.
I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205149/automating-svn-update), but could not get it.
I'm using

```
`Ubuntu version : Ubuntu 13.04`         
OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
```

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you two ways of passing passwords to SVN scripts

You can use expect [Click here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/)

or

```
--non-interactive --no-auth-cache --username XXXX --password YYYY
```

[Check Documentation here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html#svn.serverconfig.netmodel.credcache)